# Can a plumbing vent go up a different drain, for some length

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

My contractor came up with the below idea. Is it OK?

The first floor kitchen drain vent can't exit directly anymore (there's an extra room being built on top). He tells me it can tap into the drain coming down from the second floor. Because it goes above and connects with a wye, then water draining will go in the right direction (drain).

The top floor has a proper vent on top. But I'm worried that if the lower floor needs venting (either way) at the same time as someone showers on the top floor, the vent and drain will interact badly.

Are my concerns valid ?

[image]

Comment: In plumbing "Y" is spelled Wye, and an "L" is Ell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your concerns are valid:

The provided sketch would not pass any plumbing code that I am aware of. It indicates a vent from a separately vented fixture connecting to the drain portion of another fixture.

The upper end of vents need to connect to other vents or terminate to open air. They cannot connect to the drain portion of a drainage system.

Regarding other comments that the provided sketch illustrates a wet vent: It does not. Wet vented fixtures share the same drain pipe. There is no dry potion of vent between the fixtures and the wet vent potion is sized as such.

The below sketch shows the two common vent options for this scenario.

[image]

The left sketch illustrates two separately vented fixtures connecting to a single common vent. Note that the vent of the lower sink can offset horizontal once it is 6" above the flood level of its sink and it can only connect to the upper sink's vent 6" above that sinks flood level rim.

The right sketch illustrates a wet vent*.

*It should be noted that a wet vent as I've depicted could only be used provided that the sinks are not already park of a wet vent with the other fixtures in the same bathroom (this is typically the case).

Comment: I think your edits make your point much clearer.